# How can I write images from my backend directly into a src attribute of an image tag?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring

I would like to read out an image with a certain ID from a Postgresql database and specify it in my frontend (React) directly in the src attribute of an image.

My simple html code from a React App looks like this:

```
<img src={`${url}/EinzelBild/7`}  height="130px"  />
```

My backend was developed with Spring and you should now see the image even if you only enter the URL + method name and ID in the browser, for example. At the moment I only see a black screen with a small square on it.
The images are stored in the Postgresql database as type bytea.:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/EinzelBild/{id}")
@CrossOrigin
public void f_pp_bild_s(HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable String id) throws IOException {

    Connection con = DBVerbindung();
    CallableStatement properCase = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    byte[] bild = null;

    if (con != null) {

        try {
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            properCase = con.prepareCall("SELECT * FROM ppm.f_pp_projektbild_s(?)");
            properCase.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id));
            rs = properCase.executeQuery();
            con.commit();

            if (rs.next()) {

                bild = rs.getBytes("projektbild_bin");

                response.setContentType("image/jpg");
                response.setContentLength(bild.length);
                OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
                o.write(bild);
                o.flush();
                o.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
            logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
            logger.warning(e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (con != null) {
                try {
                    con.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (properCase != null) {
                try {
                    properCase.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your select query looks weird, it should be smthg like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT projektbild_bin FROM ppm.f_pp_projektbild_s where id=?"
```

**What is the correct table and column name for this query?**

Also the way you create a statement, why you don't just use

```
PreparedStatement select = con.prepareStatement(sql);
select.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(id));
```

and then just process it: (for select you don't need comit, so I've omitted it)

```
rs = select.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {

            bild = rs.getBytes(1);

            response.setContentType("image/jpg");
            response.setContentLength(bild.length);
            OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
            o.write(bild);
            o.flush();
            o.close();
        }
```

Comment: And to what extent should that help me now? The actual code is the same ?!

Comment: @user3515460 Has your code the same sql query or different?

Comment: My frontend goes to my backend (http: // localhost: 8080 / EinzelBild / 7). My backend calls a PostGrE function, delivers the image and I would like to specify this directly in the src so that the image is displayed directly in the image tag